# installing pygame in python, but untill now doesnt work

Tags: python, pygame, installation

I try to install pygame. But untill now doesnt work.

If i go to: `http://localhost:17714/`

I see this:

[image]

And if I try to install pygame like this:

[image]

I also went to:

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame
```

And I added the .whl file to this directory:

[image]

So what I am doing wrong??

Thank you!! Will be nice if somebody can help me.

But I am working on windows 10 - 64bit version

I get this error:

[image]

Oke, I could upgrade. But I still get the error:

[image]

wowwwwww:

I installed: a other version. And boemmm it works. See:

[image]

Comment: If you want to play with pygame on windows I'd suggest just using python2.7 32bit just to keep everything simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this website:
https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/
I had a look at the comments and it looks like a majority got it to work

Comment: HI, thank you for your reply. See my edit post

Comment: Thank you!! I just tried all the version. And the last version of 32 worked for me!!

Comment: But why is it so difficult to install pygame on windows?? Python is one of the most used program languages